# (T_ENDFOREACH) php error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Creating a wordpress website and I'm getting the following php error:
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in /home/soralmedia/public_html/wp-content/themes/Soral Media/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php on line 98*

Here's the code for the file:

```
    <?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * Shows recent orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$my_orders_columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', array(
    'order-number'  => esc_html__( 'Order', 'burst' ),
    'order-date'    => esc_html__( 'Date', 'burst' ),
    'order-status'  => esc_html__( 'Status', 'burst' ),
    'order-total'   => esc_html__( 'Total', 'burst' ),
    'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
) );

$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );

if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', esc_html__( 'Recent Orders', 'burst' ) ); ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table my_account_orders">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody><?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();

                ?>              
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    #<?php echo esc_html($order->get_order_number()); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_html(date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) )); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'burst' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                    $actions = array(
                                        'pay'    => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                            'name' => esc_html__( 'Pay', 'burst' )
                                        ),
                                        'view'   => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                            'name' => esc_html__( 'View', 'burst' )
                                        ),
                                        'cancel' => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                            'name' => esc_html__( 'Cancel', 'burst' )
                                        )
                                    );

                                    if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['pay'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( ! in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['cancel'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order ) ) {
                                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="qbutton small ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have use curly braces `{` for foreach of `$customer_orders` array, close that foreach with braces instead of `endforeach`

```
foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) { 
...

} // use braces for this foreach instead of endforeach;
```

Use either of these 2 ways:

```
<? foreach ($array as $arr): ?>
       ...
<? endforeach; ?>
```

OR

```
<? foreach ($array as $arr){ ?>
       ...
<? } ?>
```

Dont combine them else It will through an error.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add end for your conditions,replace your code with this

```
 <?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * Shows recent orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$my_orders_columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', array(
    'order-number'  => esc_html__( 'Order', 'burst' ),
    'order-date'    => esc_html__( 'Date', 'burst' ),
    'order-status'  => esc_html__( 'Status', 'burst' ),
    'order-total'   => esc_html__( 'Total', 'burst' ),
    'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
) );

$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );

if ( $customer_orders ) { ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', esc_html__( 'Recent Orders', 'burst' ) ); ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table my_account_orders">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) { ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody><?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();

                ?>              
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) { ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) { ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php }elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) { ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    #<?php echo esc_html($order->get_order_number()); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php }elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) { ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_html(date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) )); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php }elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) { ?>
                                <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>

                            <?php }elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) { ?>
                                <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'burst' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>

                            <?php }elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) { ?>
                                <?php
                                    $actions = array(
                                        'pay'    => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                            'name' => esc_html__( 'Pay', 'burst' )
                                        ),
                                        'view'   => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                            'name' => esc_html__( 'View', 'burst' )
                                        ),
                                        'cancel' => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                            'name' => esc_html__( 'Cancel', 'burst' )
                                        )
                                    );

                                    if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['pay'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( ! in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['cancel'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order ) ) {
                                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="qbutton small ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                            <?php } ?>
                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
                            <?php } ?>
```